# Sessions storage php/nginx

Tags: php, session, nginx

I'm having trouble with session variable in my setup. I'm storing some data in SESSION variables, but it seems like they're not stored properly, or at least I can't access them. On my local computr running MAMP it works ifne but in prod with php5/nginx, my session variables aren't stored. (I get an undefined index error).

I've read it can be related to the session.save_path and access rights, but I'm still confused. Where is this path defined? In my php.ini file there is this

```
;session.save_path = "/var/lib/php5"
```

But it starts with a ';' so I'm guessing it's ignored?
Also, what access should I give to the folder (once I've found it)? How can I know which user php is, and which group it belongs to? Seems like really basic stuff but I'm struggling to grasp it u__u

EDIT:
Apparently it's not a problem of permissions, since there are a lot of session folders in the directory, all created by php... So I really can't figure out why my session variables aren't accessible! :-(
It says undefined index...

Thanks in advance!
Aurélie

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed ignored if it starts with `;`. The default value is the temp directory, i.e. `/tmp`, but just to be sure, I suggest that you look in your `phpinfo()` and check it there because the file you checked might not be the only configuration your PHP uses.

The sessions path needs to be writable by PHP and it also has to be permitted by the `open_basedir` directive (if you use `open_basedir` which is highly recommended).

You use nginx so I'll assume you're using PHP-FPM. To find the PHP-FPM's user, you need to either find the `user = ...` directive in your `php-fpm.conf` (usually somewhere under `/etc`), or you can just find the running process using a tool like ps, htop, etc.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your help :)
I've checked the path where php stores sessions and they are properly stored, so it's likely something else. Although I'm confused as to what exactly is the problem :/ (as stated in the edit).